# why does my checkbox in IOS turn out to be like this

Tags: html, css, mobile, checkbox, responsive-design

I use Responsive Web design to turn my page into mobile layout, but something weird happens,, why the style of checkbox in IOS changes like that, the checkbox border disappear, and the check symbol is hollow.
please see the attachment.
The first image is the screenshot of Chrome
The first image is the screenshot of iphone4 
What should I do to make the checkbox in IOS as same as normal checkbox?

[image: chrome checkbox]

[image: ios checkbox]

Answer (score 2):

In general, you shouldn't.  Each browser and OS can style their controls differently.  This is not a part of the HTML standard.

MacOS also styles their checkboxes different, as does Linux.

Why do you feel the need to change the way the checkboxes are styled?  Users of that platform are used to the checkboxes looking the way that OS makes them.  If you style them differently, then users will find this odd.

Comment: While I agree, this sounds like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: ah, you reminds me, in fact the correct checkbox in IOS should be black background and white check symbols. There's css in my file making the background-color transparent, so the checkbox turns out to be weird.

Comment: @cimmanon - it's not a comment.  The answer is that you shouldn't do this.  And the reason is that users will not expect radically different styling, and will likely be unhappy with it.

Comment: @MystereMan That's an opinion.  If it isn't possible, that would be one thing.  "I don't feel like telling you how because you shouldn't do it anyway" isn't an answer.  People request all sorts of things that are awful for the user on SO and get their questions answered anyway.

Comment: @cimmanon - An opinion is not the same thing as a comment.  Many people don't understand why they should or shouldn't do something.  Almost anything in programming can be considered an "opinion" because there are many ways to do things.  "Don't do that" is as valid of an answer as any.

Comment: @Erik she is asking how not whether it should be done.  And she's not the only one looking how to do this.